# How to change Rails 5.2 url_for time out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On rails 5.2.0
I'm using Active_storage locally.
As describe in the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files), my app is working but I want to change the 5 minutes expiration of the download link generate by url_for.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the expiration timeout for Active Storage with the `config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in` configuration option. For example:

`config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 10.minutes`

Documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage

Thanks!

-Jeremy